# Remove specific values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following correlation matrix:

```
symbol    abc    xyz    ghj
symbol    
abc       1      0.1    -0.2
xyz       0.1    1       0.3
ghj      -0.2    0.3     1
```

I need to be able to find the standard deviation for the whole dataframe but that has to exclude the perfect correlation values, ie: the standard deviation must not take into account abc:abc, xyz:xyz, ghj:ghj

I am able to get the standard deviation for the entire dataframe using:

```
df.stack().std()
```

But this takes into account every single value which is not correct. The standard deviation should not include row/column combinations where an item is being correlated to itself (ie: 1). Is there a way to remove abc:abc, xyz:xyz, ghj:ghj. Then calculate the standard deviation.

Perhaps converting it to a dict or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) you can utilize [np.extract](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html) and [np.std](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

```
In [61]: import numpy as np

In [62]: a = np.array([[ 1. ,  0.1, -0.2],
                       [ 0.1,  1. ,  0.3],
                       [-0.2,  0.3,  1. ]])

In [63]: a
Out[63]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0.1, -0.2],
       [ 0.1,  1. ,  0.3],
       [-0.2,  0.3,  1. ]])

In [64]: calc_std = np.std(np.extract(a != 1, a))

In [65]: calc_std
Out[65]: 0.20548046676563256
```

`np.extract(a != 1, a))` returns an array containing each element of `a` which is **not equal** to 1.

The returned array looks like this:

```
In [66]: np.extract(a != 1, a)
Out[66]: array([ 0.1, -0.2,  0.1,  0.3, -0.2,  0.3])
```

After this extraction you can easily calculate the standard deviation with `np.std()`.